# Bewildered student vs. ORA-00257 Error--can I fix this? How?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, ora-00257

Of course my boss is out the day something goes wrong. It's just me, an inexperienced little student here, trying to get our website back up and running. All alone.

The oracle database our site pulls data from won't let me connect (throwing the error on our site), giving me the error: ORA-00257. In full:

**ORA-00257: archiver error. Connect internal only, until freed.
Cause: The archiver process received an error while trying to archive a redo log. If the problem is not resolved soon, the database will stop executing transactions. The most likely cause of this message is the destination device is out of space to store the redo log file.
Action: Check archiver trace file for a detailed description of the problem. Also verify that the device specified in the initialization parameter ARCHIVE_LOG_DEST is set up properly for archiving.**

All I have is the username and password into the database. And of course the Oracle SQL Developer client.

My question is: am I equipped to fix this problem? If so, how? If it's fixable (by me), and someone can explain it, can they explain it very, very slowly and painstakingly?

If anyone can help, even if it's just to say, "You're doomed!" ...thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you followed the advice of the error message and checked the archiver trace file for a detailed description of the problem and verified that the device specified in the initialization parameter ARCHIVE_LOG_DEST is set up properly for archiving?

Comment: Do you have a SYSDBA account?  Do you have root or other OS administrative access?  If the answer to either of these questions is 'No' than it is unlikely you can do anything about this problem.  And if you don't know the answer to either of these questions then the answer is 'No' (or at least I sincerely hope it is).

Comment: I'm pretty sure I don't have a sysdba account. Or any kind of administrative rights. And Thomas Owens, I have no idea what that means. There was a reason I emphasized "student" in my question!

Thank you both of your for your help. I think I'm going to have to tell everyone the site'll be down for a day until my boss comes back.

Answer (score 3):

You've probably used up all of the space on the disk/partition where the archive logs are being written.  Your DBA or DBA-standin should be involved at this point, because losing these logs will affect your ability to recover the database - Oracle is helping you by refusing transactions to make sure the database can be recovered if that is necessary.